# Store questions and answers which I ask at SO offline

Tags: support

I am new to the "IT" world. So I want to store whatever questions I ask here and the answers I get into my local machine, so that I can refer them offline for any interview. So I wanted to know is there any programmatic way of achieving this?
Thanks. And I have no other intention of this work.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to use Upper Case letters for proper nouns and the beginning of sentences?  It's hard to read things that are all lower case.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is probably connecting to the RSS feeds SO provides.

See for example [**your questions & answers RSS feed**](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/241717)

You could use a Feed Reader program (Mozilla's [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) has one built in, for example) to download, or otherwise process, your questions' RSS feed.

If you have a specific question on how to query data, ask a question here at meta.stackoverflow.com. Mind you though that the tone is sometimes rougher than on SO proper.

Unrelated to RSS and local downloading but maybe interesting if you're trying to find out more about SO's data, there is also a number of nifty [**Greasemonkey scripts**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemonkey-implementations) here on Meta to query and manipulate Stack Overflow Data.

Comment: Good idea, I forgot about the RSS feeds.

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow provides a [Creative Commons Data Dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) ([Jan 10](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)).

You can download it and parse it offline, <s>I don't think a per-user dump is available though</s>.

As [Pekka suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103469/store-questions-and-answers-which-i-ask-so-offline/2103517#2103517), you can also access your questions, answers and comments via RSS:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/241717
```

Seems to be limited to the last 30 records though.

Comment: If you have a reader that keeps the old feeds, it will remember them forever, it just won't get you old records when you first subscribe.